# How do I display the Pharo 2 welcome message?

Tags: pharo

I closed the workspace that is titled "Welcome to Pharo 2.0".  How do I open it again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try opening a new empty workspace and use the triangle on top right to get to the "previous contents" entry. You should find the default "Welcome to Pharo 2.0" text there:

[image]